# Is it possible to have just a part of a margin in a binding in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, margins

I have a XAML, containing information like this:

```
... Margin="10,20,30,40" ...
```

I know that it is very easy to set the left margin in a binding, as such:

```
Margin="{Binding margin_value}"
```

... but this would not fill in the values "20, 30, 40".

Everywhere I search on the internet, I see the same answer:

> You are looking for Top, Left, Bottom and Right. In order to fill those in, here's the C# code.

I'm not interested in C# code, I would like to set it in the XAML directly as a binding result, but everything I tried (`Margin.X="{Binding ...}"`, `Margin.Left="{Binding ...}"`, `Left.Margin="{Binding ...}"`, ...) seem not to work, although I'm convinced it should be really easy.

Does anybody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I *suspect* you could do it with a custom converter, using a converter parameter to give more information. For example, `Margin={Binding margin_value, Converter={StaticResource CustomMarginConverter}, ConverterParameter=x,20,30,40}`. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: If you do not specify one of the 4 properties, it'll be implicitly Zero. A Margin has one complex value of type `Thickness`. A thickness always has its 4 ltrb dimensions. So in the end, you will always specify all 4 value even if you have a converter or markup extenion or whatsoever that enables you to ommit specifiying one or the other of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify as few or many of the four Thickness-Properties as you like, be it one, two, three or four out of `Left`, `Top`, `Left` or `Buttom`.

However ommitting one just will implicitly make it hold the value of 0.

So all you gain is not writing the 0.

WPF built-in converter for `Margin` or other properties of type `Thickness` takes 1, 2 or 4 arguments but not 3.

 And when you specify one or two its just a shorthand and all four value(s) are applied anyways.
So if you don't want to specify one of them you can do it with a more verbose syntax that names the properties:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello">
  <TextBox.Margin>
      <Thickness Left="8" Top="2" Bottom="2" /><!-- Right missing -->
  </TextBox.Margin>
</TextBox>

<TextBox Text="Hello">
  <TextBox.Margin>
      <Thickness Right="10" /><!-- Left Top Bottom -->
  </TextBox.Margin>
</TextBox>
```

But as already stated this is just kind of a lengthy way for specifying this markup:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello" Margin="8 2 0 2" />
<TextBox Text="Hello" Margin="0 0 10 0" />
```

Moreover a thickness is just a plain struct, it has no dependency properties. So you can't bind to the named four dimension properties.
Conclusion: Use the built-in type converter and specify all 4 values where the shorthands don't satisfy your demands.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want can be achieved with attached properties like the following.

```cs
public static class Margin
{
    public static double GetLeft(DependencyObject obj) => (double)obj.GetValue(LeftProperty);
    public static void SetLeft(DependencyObject obj, double value) => obj.SetValue(LeftProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Left", typeof(double), typeof(Margin),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: 0D,
                propertyChangedCallback: (d, e) =>
                {
                    if (d is FrameworkElement element)
                    {
                        element.Margin = new Thickness((double)e.NewValue, 0, 0, 0);

                        // If the other values should be kept.
                        // element.Margin = new Thickness((double)e.NewValue, element.Margin.Top, element.Margin.Right, element.Margin.Bottom);
                    }
                }));
}
```

```xml
<Button local:Margin.Left="100"/>
```

You can add Top, Right, Bottom, or something as well.